# Syntax error with multiple exports including a renamed HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

I want to have multiple exports from the same file, one of them being a higher order component that is renamed as default, but I'm receiving a syntax error.

```
//Shape.js
import React, { createContext, memo } from "react";

const ResizeAPI = createContext();

const Shape = (props) => {

    /* ... */
}

export {
    
    memo(Shape) as default, // <-- Syntax/Parsing Error: Unexpected token, expected ","
    ResizeAPI
};
```

If I don't wrap the `Shape` component there is no syntax error:

```
export {
    
    Shape as default, // <-- This is fine
    ResizeAPI
};
```

Also, if I export only the main component, even if it's wrapped, there is no syntax error:

```
export default memo(List); // <-- This is fine
```

How can I export a renamed HOC within a list of exports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you export an object without a valid key, but you also can't have a key with `as default` syntax, try something like:

```
// preferable
export default memo(Shape);
export { ResizeAPI };

// or
const MemoShape = memo(Shape);
export { MemoShape as default, ResizeAPI };
```